# What are the highest permissible current harmonics input to the grid?

Tags: high-voltage, solar-energy, power-engineering, harmonics

I'm in the process of completing my Master Thesis and I need to model the current harmonics input of large-scale PV plant into the grid. We're talking about 100MW connected to the 110kV line, using EMTP-RV software.

In order to model the current harmonics, I need the magnetization current percentage of each higher harmonic, in respect to the fundamental harmonic (50Hz in my case). I've read the IEC 61000-3-2 standard, but it is applied to the system voltage not less than 220kV, which has stricter limits, compared to the lower, 110kV system.

I would appreciate the guidance on this matter. A reference conference paper/publication or standard would best suit my needs, as I can not just make things up here.

[This](https://emtp.com/applications/renewable-energy-systems) is how the harmonics are modeled in the EMTP software.

Comment: Where? In teh UK, this may be covered by G99 - see https://www.enwl.co.uk/get-connected/apply-for-a-new-connection/generation-and-storage/g99/ for a starting point.

Comment: G99 here. https://www.energynetworks.org/assets/images/Resource%20library/ENA_EREC_G99_Issue_1_Amendment_6_(2020).pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at 50 Hz, I assume you're talking about the european synchronous grid. In europe there are some harmonised grid code compliance standards. These can be found here:

- [Commission Regulation (EU) 2016/631 of 14 April 2016](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=OJ:JOL_2016_112_R_0001)
- EN 50549
- [ENTSO-E](https://www.entsoe.eu/)

Based on the available standards, I see no specific guidelines for high voltage PV plants and current harmonics. I'd assume each operator wants to do their own modeling, perhaps there are IEEE documents on this subject.

*My dealings with these regulations only applies to synchronous machines, so not much attention was put on current harmonics.*

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Your comment did remind me of looking into the national Grid Codes. Turns out, they do not specify the current injection harmonics, but rather solely voltage. So huge thanks for that ! I still need relevant data to model current harmonic injection though.

Comment: I'm assuming this is too late, but the data you need to model current harmonic injection is something the turbine manufacturers give out, if they have to. They don't like to share this for some reason, but I have values from both Vestas and Siemens. I can't share them unfortunately. And you are correct, the grid codes describe only voltages.